# The English name of yellow seeds fed to pet birds like budgies?

Tags: seeds

I asked at a bird seed shop in India, but the person called the seeds "kangni", which is [Foxtail millet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foxtail_millet), and the [seeds are different](http://homeofspices.com/product/foxtail-millet) from what is also listed as ["kangni" on other websites](https://www.indiamart.com/proddetail/kangni-13675409812.html).

I'm hoping to know the English name for these yellow seeds that are fed to small birds like budgies:
[image]

**Update:** It sprouted into this kind of a plant. I'm assuming it's some ordinary kind of grass or a millet.
[image]

Comment: Typical "budgie seed" bought in the UK is a mix of several varieties of millet, Canary grass seed, and sometimes other ingredients. They are often also given stalks of foxtail millet as well.

Comment: Sure, but I wanted to know the name of the seeds shown in the photo I posted in my question.